# How to make fullscreen picture in a meteor/react setup?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, fullscreen

I am currently working on this repo with my friend: https://github.com/openteach/openteach.

I have this bug that I can not fix. I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work?!

I have attached a picture of the bug.

Any help/ideas is appreciated.

Thanks.

Picture of bug:
  [Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBVml.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as Mike King suggest, just remember to set the background size to cover aswell:

```
background-size: cover;
```

This will make sure the background will always cover all of it's element, no matter what size the image is.

Another thing could be the element is not taking all of the height of the viewport. This can be fixed by setting the height relative to the viewport like:

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(assets/images/stardust.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the background on the body, and you won't have a gap any more

```
body{
    background: url(assets/images/stardust.png);
}
```

The sum of the heights doesn't fill the whole page, and you only have the background on the `<div class="App_component">`

The other way is to set that class on the body tag:

```
<body class="App_component">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that when I do that the body on the dashboard (localhost:3000/u/dashboard) also get the background which is not suppose to happen!? I don't know if it is because I am working with components in React?

Comment: It's not a React problem, it's a HTML layout chellenge. I think another DIV (think like a footer element) to fill the remaining space, not sure how to do that, maybe height=auto (there should be an answer on stackoverflow somewhere for that)

Comment: Thanks Mike King. I will check the Stack again :-)